# Rebuilding app with StreamBuilder (beginner) | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tree, widget, builder

This is my widget tree:

[image: Widget tree]

I have **StreamBuilder** **(`PURPLE`)**  which is re-building app after clicking **FloatingActionButton** **(`RED`)**.

**Where the problem is**

**StreamBuilder** rebuilds only objects under him, that means **UserSettingsPage** **(`GREEN`)** isn't getting rebuild. I want him to be rebuild.

**My thoughts about fixing it**

1.) I think I can maybe move my **StreamBuilder** above MateriallApp, but I don't know how to implement it.

2.) Maybe i can somehow move **UserSettingsPage** next to **HomePage**

I am open for every solution.

**(`main.dart`)**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => GoogleSignInProvider()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ThemesProvider()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ZmienneClass())
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: Provider.of<ThemesProvider>(context).darkModeOn
            ? ThemeOptions.white
            : ThemeOptions.black,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: StreamBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                //// 2 OPCJA - DODAĆ TU NAVIGATOR I PRZECZYTAĆ TO
                return const HomePage();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(child: Text("Something went Wrong.."));
              } else {
                return const LoginPage();
              }
            },
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

I am opening **UserSettingsPage** via clicking on **FloatingActionButton** **(`RED`)** which is in **UserPage**.

**Here is his code :**

```
 onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const UserSettingsPage()));
          },
```

**(`HomePage`)**

```
import 'package:flany/userpage.dart';
import 'package:flany/widgets/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key, firTime, secTime}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screens = [
      Container(),
      Game(),
      const UserPage(),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.score), label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.games_rounded), label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: ""),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex),
        body: IndexedStack(index: _selectedIndex, children: screens));
  }
}
```

**(`UserPage`)**

```
import 'package:flany/settingspage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserPageState createState() => _UserPageState();
}

class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const UserSettingsPage()));
        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.settings,
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: const [
          // SOME WIDGETS
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**(`UserSettingsPage`)**

```
class UserSettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserSettingsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserSettingsPageState createState() => _UserSettingsPageState();
}

class _UserSettingsPageState extends State<UserSettingsPage> {
// I ADDED THOSE VARIABLES
    final provider = Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: true);

    final _uLoggedWithGoogle =
        Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context).isLoggedWithGoogle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(children: [
// I ADDED CHECKING LOGIN STATUS, ITS WORKING. ITS UPDATING BUT //NOTHING ELSE HAPPENS
Text('You are logged ${_uLoggedWithGoogle() ? 'in' : 'out'}'),
        // BUTTON WHO IS EXECUTING STREAMBUILDER (onpressed code of it)
        onPressed: () {
          final provider =
             Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false);
          provider.logout();
        },
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

**(`GoogleSignInProvider`)**

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
// LOGOWANIE PRZEZ EMAIL I HASŁO LOGOWANIE PRZEZ EMAIL I HASŁO

  bool isLoggedWithGoogle() {
    var provUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (provUser?.providerData[0].providerId == "google.com") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future logout() async {
    var provUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (provUser!.providerData[0].providerId == "google.com") {
      await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    }
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    isLoggedWithGoogle() == false;

    notifyListeners();
  }}
```

Comment: Also, where exactly does the UsersSettingsPage come in? Plz show us the code!

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. You can use some state management like bloc or provider. Or what about wrapping the user settings page in a stream builder?

Comment: I didn't use Bloc, i used Providers, i would be very greatfull for one of these. Wrapping user settings in stream builder sounds great, i thought about that but i don't know how to do it in code

Comment: Ok, so this `onPressed` is in the `floatingActionButton` property of the Scaffold that's the child of the MaterialApp... correct? (Just show the whole thing!...)

Comment: No, **floatingActionButton** is property of Scaffold that is in class called **UserPage**, rebuilding depends on login status of user. If user is logged in, he is moved to **HomePage**, There i have **BottomNavigationBar**, after user chose index, he is in **UserPage**, there we have Scaffold and in it we have **FloatingActionButton**, after click on it we are in **UserSettingsPage** and i want to rebuild it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `UserSettingsPage()` to update while looking at it, in response to a button press on that same screen, which triggers a change in login status, here is one way to solve that using a `Provider` (as I can see you are already using one on this page):

```
// The way it is written right now, this could just as well be a
// StatelessWidget, but I'm keeping it Stateful since that's what you wrote.
class UserSettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserSettingsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserSettingsPageState createState() => _UserSettingsPageState();
}

class _UserSettingsPageState extends State<UserSettingsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Declare your provider first thing in the build method, and make it listen:
    final provider = Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: true);
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(children: [
        // Below, I have used your provider to change the output on the screen.
        // Since I have not seen your provider file, I don't know how it works,
        // but I assume there is a way for it to tell if the user is logged in
        // or not! :) Plz change your code to the correct way. This is just
        // an example:
        Text('You are logged ${provider.loggedIn ? 'in' : 'out'}'),
        // BUTTON WHO IS EXECUTING STREAMBUILDER
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
          provider.logout();
        },
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

My provider file used above would look something like this:

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool loggedIn = false;

  void login() {
    googleObject.login();
    loggedIn = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void logout() {
    googleObject.logout();
    loggedIn = false;
    notifyListeners();
    // The above will notify your UserSettingsPage that 
    // loggedIn has changed to false. It will update its
    // UI accordingly.
  }
}
```

Do tell me how it goes!

---

Edit

Now, I believe I have understood that with "rebuild", you don't mean rebuild that screen (as I showed above) but rebuild the app from the first screen, popping any new screens that may have been pushed on top, such as the UserSettingsPage().

There are two ways to do this.

**Method 1**

If you want the StreamBuilder to be in charge of the popping, you write it like this:

```
      body: StreamBuilder(
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //// 2 OPCJA - DODAĆ TU NAVIGATOR I PRZECZYTAĆ TO
            return const HomePage();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(child: Text("Something went Wrong.."));
          } else {
            // The below command will pop all screens that may have been pushed
            // on top of this one, every time this part of the if statement is triggered:
            Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
            // It will pop screens until it reaches the first screen.
            // You can put this in other parts of the StreamBuilder as well, every time
            // you want the app to start over from the first screen.

            return const LoginPage();
          }
        },
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      ),
```

**Method 2**

Another method is to pop the UserSettingsPage() from inside the Log Out button:

```
        onPressed: () {
          provider.logout();
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
```

The latter means you have to put the `pop` command in EVERY place where you want a screen to pop, whereas putting it in the StreamBuilder means having all the pops in one place. Which one to chose depends on your preferences!

#### Explanation

I believe part of your problem with this is that you are confused about what a screen is in Flutter. You think of your `HomePage()` and your `LoginPage()` as two different screens, correct? Well, they are not! The way you have written your code, those are just two different widgets, both displayed on your *first* screen under different circumstances.

Your `UserSettingsPage()` on the other hand, THAT ONE is a new screen! This new screen is placed on top of the first screen in a so-called "stack".

How do I know this?

Well, it is the `Navigator` that decides if something is a new screen or not. This command `Navigator.push` which you used to get to your `UserSettingsPage()` created a new screen. If you don't use this command, you will still be on the same screen as before.

When you say that you want the StreamBuilder to "rebuild the app", I think you mean that you want it to rebuild the app from the first screen. You say that "nothing else happens" but it actually does! I'm sure your *first* screen has changed from the `HomePage()` widget to the `LoginPage()` widget just as you wanted! The reason you don't see it is that your second screen is still on top, covering your first screen. But you can see it by tapping your "Back" button on your phone, since this will pop that screen.

My solutions above just pop it automatically.

Comment: It's not working beacuse i need to rebuild entire Page.

Comment: I added every page, thanks for help and engagement

Comment: Did you solve this yet? I've been away for a while...

Comment: I finally didn't

Comment: What does this part mean: `body: ListView(children: const [ // BUTTON WHO IS EXECUTING STREAMBUILDER]),`? The StreamBuilder is on your first page! How can it be "executed" from a different page, further down the widget tree?

Comment: by saing "executed" i meant code who is notifying StreamBuilder about that it needs to rebuild Widgets, it's a google log out button.

Comment: Ah! That makes so much sense, now... So the problem is that when you log out, you want the UserSettingsPage to automatically update, but instead nothing visible happens, is that correct? If so, could you plz clarify exactly what it is you want to happen when clicking this log out button?

Comment: The general answer is still that your UserSettingsPage needs to have its own stream with a setState(), a Provider or similar, so that it can rebuild in response to a change in login status.

Comment: See Edit in my answer above.

Comment: Exactly, nothing happens after clicking "log out"

Comment: It's because you haven't told it what you want to happen. You've only told the StreamBuilder what to show on the first page, but not what to happen AFTER it has already pushed a new screen from there, and a change occurs. If, for example, you want the settings screen to pop on logout, you have to tell it to do so. This can be done on the settings page or in the StreamBuilder... but make sure you use the right context to pop! Did you try my Edit?

Comment: Now it's only updating my Text('You are logged ${isLoggedWithGoogle() ? 'in' : 'out'}') part. I am adding my GoogleSignInProvider code.
And still nothing except that happens

Comment: I also added changes to **```UserSettingsPage```**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248343/discussion-between-karolina-hagegard-and-malak).

Comment: I made one final clean-writing of my answer above, including also the explanation for future readers.  @Malak, plz see chat again.

Comment: Btw, I just saw this: `isLoggedWithGoogle() == false;`. This is nonsense code!  (You're asking if the function equals false... but then you put a `;` ending the question without any action.) Remove this line, as it does nothing. Then re-write your `GoogleSignInProvider` to look more like mine above, with a simple `bool` variable that you change between true and false upon login and logout, and then notify listeners each time.

Comment: Plz see chat, as well! https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248343/discussion-between-karolina-hagegard-and-malak